# Estimate dimensions of a functions parameter array

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

Theoretically the type should be known at compile time and the compiler is also aware about the dimensions. Currently, I have a template functions which takes the dimensions of a matrix as template parameters. Can I somehow avoid this by estimating the dimensions in constexpr or via template functions?

```
struct cont {};
void ffd<3>::run(cont mat[3][3][3])
```

In comprehension, I want to avoid declaring the `rows` parameter.

```
template<uint8_t rows>
struct ffd {
  template<class T>
  static float run(const T &mat) {
      // recursion over the rows in mat
  }
};
```

Comment: So you want to get `rows` from `T` at compile time?

Comment: My first thought was also it shouldn't be possible. But the type is known at compile time, isn't it?

Comment: I can see 3 instances of the 3 template parameter, in addition to the number of dimensions which is also 3. What would be the parameters of void `ffd<4>::run`? `void ffd<4>::run(float mat[4][4][4])`, `void ffd<4>::run(float mat[3][3][3][3])` or still something else? Currently your question is *unclear*...

Comment: It is not unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are searching for is [std::extent](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent):

> ```
> template< class T, unsigned N = 0>
> struct extent;
> ```

which

> If T is an array type, provides the member constant value equal to the
>   number of elements along the Nth dimension of the array, if N is in
>   [0, std::rank::value)

---

For example, for

```
float a[10][11][12];
```

when called `run(a)`:

```
template<class T>
float run(const T &mat)
{
   std::extent<T, 0>::value; // 10
   std::extent<T, 1>::value; // 11
   std::extent<T, 2>::value; // 12

}
```

Comment: @dgrat you have the same problem as in your previous example. Here array decay to pointer happens at the parameter of `proxy`.The real parameter type of `proxy` is `int (*)[5][6]`.